# How to close a constructor frame?

Tags: java

```
public class RainfallStudy extends JFrame{
/**
 * Declare global variables
 */
int x = 20, y = 567; //starting location for the title 
int xSpeed = 20, ySpeed = 20; // the speed for x and y directions
int delay = 20; // to slow down my title 
ImageIcon BackGnd, pic; // variables for the pictures

/**
 * Constructor to build the frame
 */
public RainfallStudy() {
    // this builds a window with a title
    super("Weather Report");
    setSize(1000,567);

    //loading the picture files
    BackGnd = new ImageIcon ("weatherBack.png");
    pic = new ImageIcon ("weatherIcon.png");

    setResizable(false);
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
```

This is how I made my frame, I then did my animations in `public void paint(Graphics g)`.

now after I call it in the main using `new RainfallStudy();`, the window stays open after the animation is done, how can I manually close it?

Comment: The code that does the animations needs to dispose the JFrame or make it invisible `setVisible(false);` once the animation is complete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it work to call [dispose](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#dispose--) or [setVisible](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setVisible-boolean-) on the RainfallStudy instance? For example:

```
RainfallStudy rs = new RainfallStudy();
rs.setVisible(false);
```

Comment: It tells me 'dispose cannot be resolved or is not a field' and 'Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method setVisible(boolean) from the type Window'

Comment: Edited my answer to make it a little clearer how you’d call it on the RainfallStudy instance

Comment: It didn't close the window, I didn't get a error but it didn't do anything

Comment: You’re calling `setVisible` on the `RainfallStudy` instance you created, not pasting my code exactly, right? Does `dispose` work if `setVisible` doesn’t? Otherwise, I’d probably use a debugger or similar to make sure it’s reaching that command.

Comment: Yeah I am, I also tried calling it in different ways and I ended up with an infinite loop that was quite problematic to shut down but I did manage to get dispose work, Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Great, you’re welcome!

Comment: @D2K6 remember to [accept this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) since it solved your problem.